# How can I get my Chromecast receiver listed on the app page after it's already been published?

Tags: chromecast

My custom Chromecast receiver was originally published with the "Listing Details" toggled off in the Developer Console, so that it doesn't show up on http://chromecast.com/apps. Now, I'd like it to be listed, so I toggled the listing setting on and saved.

[Listing Details toggled on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s52UF.png)

We waited two days in case maybe a cache just needed to be cleared on Google's side, but it still doesn't appear when searching the app name on the listing page. All of the listing metadata is correct. Unpublishing and re-publishing is only a last-resort option for me as this receiver is live and used by hundreds of consumers daily. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation - **[Google Cast : Registration](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration)**, on the Edit application information part:

> 8. In the Listing Details section, choose whether to list your application on Google properties such as chromecast.com/apps.

#### You must publish (or republish) your app in order for these edits to take effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unpublish followed by publish doesn't seem to help. What am I missing?